# Google Cloud DNS went down or kicked me out?

Tags: dns, cloud

Today I changed my nameservers to ns-cloud-c1, c2 and c3... I didn't had the option to add a 4th.

After the change my website ran perfect. But after an hour, suddenly my domain didn't had any Nameservers specified! Website down, mail down, everything down. 
How can that be?!

Comment: In the beginning when the website was running great, at mxtoolbox I got messages about the parent.

Answer (score 0):

DNSSEC was in use on my domain. With DNSSEC enabled it becomes very hard to change your nameservers... Tip for everybody else: aks your hosting company to disable DNSSEC first.